# Calling Java Method from Servlet 2.5

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, el

I got this little code snippet from one of my `JSP` files:

```
 <c:when test="${not empty param['filePath'] && not empty param['revision']}">
<c:out value="${sessionScope.fileHelper.getContentsForPath(param.filePath,param.revision)}" escapeXml="false"/>
</c:when>
```

Unfortunately I have to migrate back to `Servlet 2.5`, currently I was using `3.0`.

The problem with this is, that `EL (Expression Language)` does not support calling methods like this in prior versions. So I asked me how to accomplish the same thing with `2.5` compatible code.

The `fileHelper` gets added to the `sessionScope` in a different `JSP` file like:

```
<jsp:useBean id="fileHelper"
    class="de.myPackage.util.FileHelper" scope="session" />
```

What I tried was:

```
<%@ page import="de.myPackage.util.FileHelper"%>

<c:when test="${not empty param['filePath'] && not empty param['revision']}">
<c:out value="<%=(FileHelper)session.getAttribute("fileHelper").getContentsForPath(request.getParameter("filePath"),(String)request.getParameter("revision"))%>" escapeXml="false"/>
</c:when>
```

But this doesn't work since it writes:

> The method getContentsForPath(String, String) is undefined for the type Object.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap the cast session object within `()` to use it's `.getContentsForPath()` method. Something like this:

```
((FileHelper) session.getAttribute("fileHelper")).getContentsForPath(...)
```